# Python regular expression to find and replace multiple matches

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string as follows which can have any number of spaces after the first [ or before the last ]:

```
my_string = " [  0.53119281  1.53762345  ]"
```

I have a regular expression which matches and replaces  each one individually as follows:

```
my_regex_start = "(\[\s+)" #Find square bracket and any number of white spaces
replaced_1 = re.sub(my_regex_start, '[', my_string) --> "[0.53119281  -0.16633733  ]"

my_regex_end = "(\s+\])" #Find any number of white spaces and a square bracket
replaced_2 = re.sub(my_regex_end, ']', my_string) -->" [   0.53119281  -0.16633733]"
```

I have a regular expression which finds one OR the other:

```
my_regex_both = "(\[\s+)|(\s+\])" ##Find square bracket and any number of white spaces OR ny number of white spaces and a square bracket
```

How can I use this **my_regex_both** to replace the first one and OR the second one if any or both are found?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of catching the brackets, you can replace the spaces that are preceded by `[` or followed by `]` with an empty string:

```
import re

my_string = "[  0.53119281  1.53762345  ]"

my_regex_both = r"(?<=\[)\s+|\s+(?=\])"

replaced = re.sub(my_regex_both, '', my_string)

print(replaced)
```

Output:

```
[0.53119281  1.53762345]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use aside from MrGeek's answer would be to use a capture group to catch everything between your `my_regex_start` and `my_regex_end` like so:

```
import re

string1 = " [  0.53119281  1.53762345  ]"

result = re.sub(r"(\[\s+)(.*?)(\s+\])", r"[\2]", string1)
print(result)
```

I have just sandwiched `(.*?)` between your two expressions.  This will lazily catch what is between which can be used with `\2`

OUTPUT

```
[0.53119281  1.53762345]
```